# fetch attactments - imap_fetchbody()

Tags: php, imap

How to fetch attachments in an email?

## code

```
$structure = imap_fetchstructure($this->stream, $this->msgno);
//print_r($structure);
if(isset($structure->parts)){
    foreach($structure->parts as $section => $part){
        if(isset($part->disposition)){
            if(strtolower($part->disposition) == 'attachment'){
                echo 'section = '.$section."\n";
                $body = imap_fetchbody($this->stream, $this->msgno, $section);
                
                $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
                echo $finfo->buffer($body) . "\n";
                
                $file = Init::$dynamic['data_path'].$this->msgno.'_'.$part->dparameters[0]->value;
                
                imap_savebody($this->stream, $file, $this->msgno, $section);
                
                echo $finfo->file($file) . "\n";
                
                //print_r($body);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the returned attachments isn't even near the correct file size and the returned data looks something like this

```
ZHUga2VuZGVyIHZlbCBpa2tlIG5vZ2VuIHNvbSBlciB2ZWQgYXQgc3RhcnRlIGVnZW4gdmly
a3NvbWhlZCBlbGxlciBzb20gbGlnZSBlciBzdGFydGV0IG9wPyA6KQ0KDQpmb3JkaSBqZWcg
bmV0b3AgZXIgYmxldmV0IGbmcmRpZyBtZWQgYXQgbGF2ZSBldCD4a29ub21pc3lzdGVtIG1l
ZCBlbiByZXZpc29yIHNvbSBlciB1ZHZpa2xldCBtZWQgc+ZybGlndCBoZW5ibGlrIHDlIGl2
5nJrc+Z0dGVyZSBzb20gb2Z0ZSBpa2tlIGhhciBkZW4gc3RvcmUgaW5kc2lndCBpIPhrb25v
bWkgOik=
```

Identical files either has the same file size even if they are copies

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-base64.php will probably help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your make your code complicate.

Your problem is you did not get your encode data

```
$body = imap_fetchbody($this->stream, $this->msgno, $part);
//$part=2 (first attachment file)
//$part=3 (second attachment file) ...
```

before you can get your real data in that file please take a look at

```
$coding = $structure->parts[$part]->encoding;
if ($coding == 0) {
    $body = imap_7bit($body);
} elseif ($coding == 1) {
    $body= imap_8bit($body);
} elseif ($coding == 2) {
    $body = imap_binary($body);
} elseif ($coding == 3) {
    $body = imap_base64($body);
} elseif ($coding == 4) {
    $body = imap_qprint($body);
} elseif ($coding == 5) {
    $body = $body;
}
```

so you can try to print this out :

```
echo $body;
```

Note : $section is the part of your files.

Answer (score 1):

What you've got there is an ASCII representation of binary data, encoded using an encoding scheme called [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). Use [base64_decode](http://php.net/base64_decode) to access the binary data once you've received the string entirely, which is usually indicated by a trailing `=`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$emailtop= imap_search($inbox,'SUBJECT "'.$word.'" SINCE "'.sinceDate.'" BEFORE "'.beforeDate.'"');



/* if any emails found, iterate through each email */
if($emailtop) {

    /* put the newest emails on top */
    //rsort($emails);
   //print_r($emails); //die;
    /* for every email... */
    foreach($emailtop as $email_number) 
    {
        echo "</br> emailtop".$email_number;

        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
        echo '</br><span class="subject">'.$overview[0]->subject.'</span> ';
         //echo  'ds</br><span class="subject">'.$overview[0]->subject.'</span> ';
         if (!file_exists($dateTime)) {
            mkdir($dateTime, 0777, true);
        }

         /* get mail structure */
        $structure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox, $email_number);

        $attachments = array();

        /* if any attachments found... */
        if(isset($structure->parts) && count($structure->parts)) 
        {
            echo "<pre>";print_r($structure->parts);

            for($i = 0; $i < count($structure->parts); $i++) 
            {
                if(isset($structure->parts[$i]->parts) && !empty($structure->parts[$i]->parts) && count($structure->parts[$i]->parts)>0)
                {
                    echo "</br> SubCategory".$email_number;
                    //echo "<pre>";print_r($structure->parts[$i]);
                    for($y = 0; $y < count($structure->parts[$i]->parts); $y++) 
                    {
                        echo "</br> SubCategory loop".$email_number;
                        //echo "<pre>";print_r($structure->parts[$i]->parts);
                        $attachments[$y] = array(
                        'is_attachment' => false,
                        'filename' => '',
                        'name' => '',
                        'attachment' => ''
                    );

                     //die;

                    if($structure->parts[$i]->parts[$y]->ifdparameters==1) 
                    {


                        foreach($structure->parts[$i]->parts[$y]->dparameters as $object) 
                        {

                            if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'filename') 
                            {
                                $attachments[$y]['is_attachment'] = true;
                                $attachments[$y]['filename'] = $object->value;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if($structure->parts[$i]->parts[$y]->ifparameters) 
                    {
                        foreach($structure->parts[$i]->parts[$y]->parameters as $object) 
                        {
                            if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name') 
                            {
                                $attachments[$y]['is_attachment'] = true;
                                $attachments[$y]['name'] = $object->value;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if($attachments[$y]['is_attachment']) 
                    {
                        $attachments[$y]['attachment'] = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, ($i+1).'.'.($y+1));

                        /* 4 = QUOTED-PRINTABLE encoding */
                        if($structure->parts[$i]->parts[$y]->encoding == 3) 
                        { 
                            //echo "hi  ". $attachments[$y]['attachment']; die;

                            $attachments[$y]['attachment'] = base64_decode($attachments[$y]['attachment']);
                        }
                        /* 3 = BASE64 encoding */
                        elseif($structure->parts[$i]->parts[$y]->encoding == 4) 
                        { 

                            $attachments[$y]['attachment'] = quoted_printable_decode($attachments[$y]['attachment']);
                        }

                    }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "</br> Single".$email_number;
                    $attachments[$i] = array(
                        'is_attachment' => false,
                        'filename' => '',
                        'name' => '',
                        'attachment' => ''
                    );

                     //die;
                    if($structure->parts[$i]->ifdparameters==1) 
                    {


                        foreach($structure->parts[$i]->dparameters as $object) 
                        {


                            if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'filename') 
                            {
                                $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                                $attachments[$i]['filename'] = $object->value;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if($structure->parts[$i]->ifparameters) 
                    {
                        foreach($structure->parts[$i]->parameters as $object) 
                        {
                            if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name') 
                            {
                                $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                                $attachments[$i]['name'] = $object->value;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if($attachments[$i]['is_attachment']) 
                    {
                        $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, $i+1);


                        /* 4 = QUOTED-PRINTABLE encoding */
                        if($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 3) 
                        { 
                            $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = base64_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                        }
                        /* 3 = BASE64 encoding */
                        elseif($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 4) 
                        { 
                            $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = quoted_printable_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /* iterate through each attachment and save it */
        foreach($attachments as $attachment)
        {

            if($attachment['is_attachment'] == 1)
            {

                    $filename = $attachment['name'];
                    if(empty($filename)) 
                    $filename = $attachment['filename'];

                if(!in_array($filename, $dowloadAttachments))
                {   
                    $dowloadAttachments[] =  $filename;

                    /* To check extension of attachment */
                    $info = pathinfo($filename);

                    $xlsExtension = array('xls','xlsm','xlss','csv');
                    if (in_array($info["extension"],$xlsExtension)) {




                        /* prefix the email number to the filename in case two emails
                         * have the attachment with the same file name.
                         */
                         $tmpFile = $filename;
                        $filename = $dateTime."/".$filename; 
                        $fp = fopen($filename, "w+");
                        fwrite($fp, $attachment['attachment']);
                        fclose($fp);
                        require "calculateValue.php";



}
                }
            }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While code is very appreciated and helps to illustrate solution approaches, it would also be helpful if you describe your approach and maybe also illustrate different opportunities, advantages or downsides of different approaches.